# Does anyone know how to model this relationship?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, architecture, game-development

I have AI players who can partake in certain jobs. So I have to find the best way to model this relationship. The restaurant worker gets food from the restaurant inventory and brings it to the table. In this job, the restaurant inventory is the "FoodStore" and the table is the delivery point. I have the same job concept for the meat supplier, however his "Food Store" is the Distribution plant and his delivery point is the restaurant inventory. These three objects all have to "be" a goal object either thru abstract class or interface I haven't decided.

The main issue is that I cant check the "FoodAvailable" property of the objects because Im iterating through them AS their parent class "Goal" to keep things abstract so that meat supplier and restaurant worker can both implement the same "Job" class. I need to be able to iterate potential delivery points in need of food while also checking their resource value, so I need the delivery point objects to satisfy both properties while also being abstract somehow.

To complicate matters even more I have other AI that will come and eat from the tables. I seem to be doing fine with that. Modeling this particular relationship is stumping me tho. I don't think the code is relevant in this case as I just need a high level idea of how to represent it. I can provide the code if it would be helpfull.

[image]

Comment: This sound a lot like a blackboard archtecture. This structure will make it a lot easier to observe different objects and add more and more direction that objects can go (send food back to the kitchen...)

Answer (score 0):

I think I kind-of get what you're after.  There's a few options that come to mind...

1. Use interfaces or inheritance to identify objects that have a `FoodAvailable` property.  I'm assuming you have a collection/list of object to iterate over which covers all of the objects in question.
2. Nested objects.  A job might have child jobs, so when you check `FoodAvailable` on an object it would also do a `FoodAvailable` check on any child-objects they have - if any.

Here's some pseudo code showing option 2.  Not sure if my logic is 100% correct, but the general idea should be fairly clear:

```
class Job(){

  Job[] DependentJobs { ... }
  Food MyFood { ... }

  // Returns true if all required food is ready.
  bool FoodAvailable {

    get {
      // First check if this object has food in it's own right: 
      if(MyFood != ready)
        return false

      else
      // Second, if the first check passes, check child / dependent jobs: 
        foreach(job in DependentJobs){
          if(job.FoodAvailable == false) return false
        }
        return true
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

this is demo process

```
interface ItemInterface<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// itemCall
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    void SetItemData (T args);
}

public class TempItem<T>:ItemInterface<T>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// itemCall
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args"></param>
    void SetItemData (T args)
    {
        if(T is int a)
        {
            int b = a;
        }
    }
}

public void Main()
{
    object obj = createObjItem();
    //"SetItemData" is ItemInterface call Fun name
    MethodInfo method = obj.GetType ().GetMethod ("SetItemData");
    if( method != null )
    {
        int data = 1;
        method.Invoke (obj , new object [1] { data });
    }
}

private object createObjItem()
{
    TempItem<int> item = new TempItem<int>();
    //transform to obj
    object obj = item;
    return obj;
}
```

you can see see reflection and attribute